# PostGIS 3D in Action

Tags: postgis, 3d

I was wondering if there is a website that showcases Openlayers and PostGIS 3D in Action

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This uses ST_AsGeoJSON from PostGIS and **supports** 3D

[http://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html)

links to

[https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-layer.html](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/vector-formats.html)

however I have not seen Openlayers in 3D
only links

http://trac.openlayers.org/wiki/3D

Comment: Yup, I've seen the support in both PostGIS and OpenLayers, but it'll be nice to see it in Action. Perhaps a project for openstreet maps where they draw the roads per elevation, including bridges

Comment: @Mapperz the shared links are now unfortunately dead.

Comment: updated url to the best fit https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-layer.html