# What are my options for 3D web Maps?

Tags: web-mapping, 3d

I wish to have a Online 3D Map, which would show my Data, i.e both Raster and Vector, draped on a DEM that I have.

Due to the requirements of using my own DEM & Raster data, Google Earth API is pretty much out of the running.

Are there any projects which can do this?

Comment: I posted a [similar question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/postgis-3d-in-action) last year related to postgis 3d

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well, [WebGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL) is promising but has few features now. You can have a look to the [API](http://www.webglearth.org/api) and [examples](http://webglearth.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/api/examples/).

From what I know, it is supported by FF4 and Chrome 9. You will find more about browsers compatibility on their website.

Javascript libraries :

- http://cesium.agi.com/ and [demos](http://cesium.agi.com/demos.html)

To explore (samples and tutorials) :

- A quite [realistic 3D map](http://map.f4-group.com/#lon=-3.6903690&lat=42.3494437&zoom=19&camera.theta=62.55) using webGL and rendering buildings, trees and shadow.

[image: Burgos - F4]

- A WebGL application based on OpenStreetMap data (and CGIAR) developed by Technion. See the static view [clicking here](http://osm3d.cs.technion.ac.il/static/index.html?bbox=13.40473,52.51689,13.41563,52.52423) and choose the desired view from http://osm3d.cs.technion.ac.il/

[image]

- A webGL application for switzerland geoportal. Quite Impressive! See it [online](http://swiss3d.openwebglobe.org/) or have a look to [the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1mXRyfsaVQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player)
- Some news from GMaps (Oct. 2011) : http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2011/10/google-maps-in-webgl.html
- Here comes a Nokia application using WebGL : http://maps3d.svc.nokia.com/webgl/index.html
- Some WebGLEarth samples online : http://webglearth.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/api/examples/. The main demo : http://www.webglearth.com/
- *planetaryjs*, A globe JS library (added on January 2014) : http://planetaryjs.com/

Comment: +1 I didn't' know WebGLEarth existed. Here's hoping WebGL replaces Flash and other plugins for this type of application.

Comment: Although not in 3D, here is one more [example](http://ncg.nuim.ie/i2maps/docs/flowmap/index.html) of journey-to-work flows in Switzerland from [i2maps project](http://ncg.nuim.ie/i2maps/docs/) that might be helpful.

Comment: The Nokia demo is particularly impressive because unlike the other demos, it has extrusions and interesting building data.

Answer (score 14):

<s>ReadyMap might be another option.</s> [Here](http://demo.pelicanmapping.com/rmweb/webgl/tests/leaflet.html) is an example (with a bonus of Leaflet integration!) [via [@LeafletJS](https://twitter.com/#!/LeafletJS)]:

[image]

And one more with 3D overlay on the globe:

[image]

<s>More: [demos](http://demo.pelicanmapping.com/rmweb/webgl/tests/index.html), [code](https://github.com/gwaldron/godzi-webgl/wiki/ReadyMap-SDK).</s>

Update: The project seems to change its course rather drastically. [ReadyMap](http://www.readymap.org/) is now:

> Free Data Service for ReadyMap and osgEarth Developers

And the 3D globe application moved (most liklely?) to a new efforts concentrated on osgEarth ([webpage](http://osgearth.org/), [gallery](https://plus.google.com/+OsgearthOrg/posts), [source](https://github.com/gwaldron/osgearth)).

Comment: All the links seem to be dead by now.

Comment: @rotoglup Thanks for update. Indeed - project seems to not be there any longer o_O

Answer (score 4):

Handy Article on summarising the changes and practicality here:

http://www.georelated.com/2011/11/3d-gis-from-desktop-to-web.html

Also check out these guys:
http://www.webglearth.org/

Answer (score 2):

Just found this one.... OpenLayers / Cesium Hybrid:
[image]
http://jktaylor.github.com/openlayers/examples/adapters/editingtoolbar.html

## or

You could use the cesium viewer alone:
http://cesium.agi.com/CesiumViewer/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i like this implementation of WebGL, this is not a globe map style but more like DEM data, but the version 1.0 not yet available , i don't know when exactly will be available in this summer

http://openscales.org/news/openscalesgl-announce.html

Answer (score 1):

In the mean time, there is [three.js](http://threejs.org) as a wrapper around WebGL. See for an example [here](http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2013/11/showing-gps-tracks-in-3d-with-threejs.html).

Answer (score 1):

I would go a little easier and choose [Cortona 3D player](http://www.cortona3d.com/cortona3d-viewers) for visualisation and export everything in the GIS of your choice as VRML file.