# How to create 3D web application using Open Source GIS software?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, javascript, web-mapping, ext-js

I'm using OpenLayers - 2.11,GeoServer 2.13, ExtJS 3.4, and Java for developing GIS based web applications.
How can we create GIS based 3d application like below attachment using opensource softwares in GIS.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not aware of how they got this particular look. I would asume that it would invole a lot of custom artwork and manual involvement. This question might also be useful: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12859/what-are-my-options-for-3d-web-maps

Comment: dear Devdatta Tengshe..thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Can you edit your post to give links to the websites these images come from please?

Comment: http://anyang.edushi.com/ check this one..

Comment: and this http://www.reykjavikcentermap.com/..

Answer (score 2):

Check Out Cesium which is a JavaScript library for creating 3D globes and 2D maps in a web browser without a plugin. visit http://cesium.agi.com/index.html to download and try may be it will help.

Comment: My pleasure Ram:)

Answer (score 0):

Check also this open source framework I have created: https://cesiumext.github.io/cesiumext1/

It combines CesiumJs with ExtJS