# What must be learned to build 3D web map?

Tags: javascript, web-mapping, 3d-map, opengl

I wish to build a 3D web map based on Silverlight or JavaScript. I cannot build 3D in Silverlight.

What I should do then? Should I learn "Balder" or OpenGL or what?  I must do it before 09/2014. Can you give some ideas?

Comment: The question in its current state is too broad. You need to give us more details. What do you want to achieve? What features do you want in the 3D map? What would your data sources be? Anything in particular that you have looked at?

Comment: Thanks for your response, Devdatta , and the requirement is a little loose,contains 3d sense and can be query or spatial analyze.Of course,it will be better if I can have a sense of crossing the street and many things(buildings or houses) passing by.The main requirement is that I can query and operate it by using arcgis server for silverlight on the web.I do not know what technology I have to learn and do not have any document or codes to learn.Would you give me some suggestion.Thanks you.

Comment: If you are limiting yourself to silverlight, then I'm afrain that you are going to draw a blank. You'll have to start from scratch and do everything yourself. If you are willing to work with JavaScript & WebGL, you'll find several projects, to help you. Have a look at this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12859/what-are-my-options-for-3d-web-maps

Answer (score 1):

Check Out Cesium which is a JavaScript library for creating 3D globes and 2D maps in a web browser without a plugin. visit http://cesium.agi.com/index.html to download and try. I hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks farhat but the link is not avalible for me...do you have some others? Thanks you.

Comment: If you cannot access the above link i posted in my answer try google search for cesiumjs.org or visit http://cesiumjs.org/index.html